# Set CSS padding to value based on attribute

Tags: css, attr

This doesn't work:

```
li[depth="3"] { padding-left: calc(40px * attr(depth integer)); }
```

However, this works:

```
li[depth="3"] { padding-left: calc(40px * 3); }
```

---

Apparently [`attr(name type)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) is not supported inside [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)... yet.

- More information here: [On attr() and calc()](http://lea.verou.me/2010/09/on-attr-and-calc/)

**Is there any way to replace the following CSS with CSS that works for all integer values of attribute `depth`?**

```
li[depth="2"] { padding-left:  40px; }
li[depth="3"] { padding-left:  80px; }
li[depth="4"] { padding-left: 120px; }
```

Comment: "The attr() function can be used with any CSS property, but support for properties other than content is experimental."

Comment: I get the feeling that this question has resulted a problem implementing a solution to another problem although I could, of course, be wrong about that; if I'm right, though, could you explain the problem you were originally trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: @DavidThomas: I'm open to other solutions~ (I'm using a flat list instead of nested lists because I couldn't find a virtual scroll library that handled nested lists.) `depth` is the level the `li` needs to be indented. The value of `depth` is taken from the birch-outline that is being rendered. Look at the list that is rendered on the left in this demo: https://leftium.github.io/Todo.taskpaper/

Comment: Does your html need to be <ul><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul> or is open to modification?

Comment: @Alvaro: No tag structure required... in fact, I might just insert a <span> for each indent level.

Comment: So looking at your referenced link, it appears you haven't been able to find a better (and a more generic) approach to this yet!

Answer (score 2):

There is no special CSS that could achieve this - typically it's best to avoid referencing style/layout rules in the DOM. The CSS [flexbox model](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) could prove useful for this purpose, to allow the elements to size according to how many of them exist.

If you needed to go the CSS route you specified, a preprocessor like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) could allow you to automate the writing of all that code with a loop (example below in SCSS syntax) - though note that the final .css file produced will have all the rules compiled out. Also note that the range here is limited - you can adjust `20` to any amount but it won't work infinitely (though I assume it won't even reach 20 given the example).

```
@for $i from 1 to 20 {
  li[depth="#{$i}"] { padding-left: #{($i - 1) * 40px}; }
}
```

Comment: `scss` is not in the OP and your code is limited in a range definition.